# How to filter an Excel Table, copy visible Column (that has a formula), and paste the value into another visible column `Offset(0,-13)` using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy-paste

I have been researching this for days, and cannot seem to figure out a solution.

I have a `("Table1")`. In `Column "X"` there is a =SumIfs formula that will update when another report is updated.

As part of a larger macro, after the report `Refresh`, I would to:

1. Filter `Column "X"` for Non-blank rows
2. `Copy` the visible rows in Column "X"
3. Paste the value (Not the formula) into Column "K" `Offset(0,-13)`
4. Calculate to remove the Formula in Column "X"

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I found multiple links that either paste to another worksheet/workbook, try to loop through all the columns (not just the visible ones), or use an array.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471540/copying-filtered-cells-and-paste-value-only-into-filtered-cells) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516723/vba-paste-visible-cells-filtered-into-same-rows-but-another-column) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470881/copy-filtered-column-to-the-another-column-but-same-index) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924691/how-to-copy-and-paste-a-filtered-table-using-vba-from-one-column-to-another-visi)

I have been trying to recreate the code on the links to fit my needs, but I keep getting erros:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wbInventory As Workbook

Sub Test1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

    Set wbInventory = Workbooks("IWI Inventory MASTER Report.xlsm")

    With wbInventory
        With wsPOTracker '<- worksheet codename
            
            'Filter Column "X" with no blanks
            .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
                
            'Copy Filtered data, and paste in Column "P"
            Set rng = .Range("X3", .Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                    rng.Offset(0, -13).PasteSpecial '<-Doesn't paste in adjacent row, but in a block grouping

           Calculate

        End With
    End With
   
End Sub

Sub Test2()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim pRng As Range

    Set wbInventory = Workbooks("IWI Inventory MASTER Report_Template.xlsm")

    With wbInventory
        With wsPOTracker '<- worksheet codename
            
            'Filter Column "X" with no blanks
            .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
                
            'Copy Filtered data, and paste in Column "P"
            Set rng = .Range("X3", .Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                
                rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                    
                    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, -13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<- Run-time eroor '1004: This action won't work on multiple selections

           Calculate

        End With
    End With
   
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Through more research, I have learned more about `Tables`, `ListColumns`, `DataBodyRange`.  My code is now pasting into the offset column.  However, the formula also pastes into the offset column as well.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateReceivedInfo() '<-Sub is within the workbook

Dim wbInventory As Workbook
Set wbInventory = Workbooks("IWI Inventory MASTER Report.xlsb")

With wbInventory
    With wsPOTracker '<- worksheet codename
            
    Calculate
            
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
                                
    'Filter Column "X" with no blanks
    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
                
    'Set Range for Column ("X"): "Recieved Qty"
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(24).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
    'Copy Filtered data, and paste in Column ("K"): "QTY RECIEVED"
    Dim cell As Range
            
    For Each cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
                    
        cell.Copy cell.Offset(0, -13) '<- copies and pastes formula
        cell.Copy cell.Offset(0, -13).PasteSpecial xlpastevalues '<-Compile error: Expected: End of statement
        cell.Value2 cell.Offset(0, -13).Value2 '<- Compile error: Invalid use of property

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next cell
    
    Calculate
    .ShowAllData
            
    End With
End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Option Explicit` and you don't declare `wsPotracker`.  That is likely your first error.  When you say you keep getting errors, please specify where you are getting the error and what the error says.

Comment: @DarrellH This macro is within the same workbook, and the worksheets all have codenames. 
I marked with a 'note where the Test 1 & 2 would have an error. 

The Test 4 actually works.  However it pastes the formula into Column "P".  I need to be able to paste the `Values` into Column "P"; not the formula

Comment: `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` also noted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial

Comment: @DarrellH `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is throwing a Compile Error: Expected: end of statement

Comment: Have you tried `For Each cell In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible): cell.Offset(0, -13) = cell.Value: Next`  ?  ---OR---  if you are sure that after you filter for the non-blank rows, all the visible cells are formula, then maybe you want to try without filtering at all but `For Each cell In .ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("IWI RECEIVING QTY").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas): cell.Offset(0, -13).Value = cell.Value: Next` ---> this will loop to only cell which has formula, then it put the value  of the looped-cell to the looped-cell.offset(0,-13).

Comment: @karma Thank you - I didn't know I could do `cell.Offset(0, -13) = cell.Value` with a Table API!
Yes, in `.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(24).DataBodyRange` has the SumIfs formula in all rows to populate `IF([@[QTY RECEIVED]]=""` (is blank).

I wouldn't want to I use your second suggestion `.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("IWI RECEIVING QTY").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas): cell.Offset(0, -13).Value = cell.Value: Next`, because it would erase any data that may already be in `Column("K")`

Comment: @CDay, I think both of my suggestion would erase any data that may already be in column K. Example : after filtering column X to non-blank, it loop to the visible cells - but before it write to cell.offset(0,-13) it doesn't check first whether cell.offset(0,-13) is blank or has value. So, to avoid it overwrite existing value (if any) in column K then I think it should be `For Each cell In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible): if cell.Offset(0, -13).value = "" then cell.offset(0,-13).value = cell.Value: Next` The same thing ... (continue)

Comment: `For Each cell In .ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("IWI RECEIVING QTY").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas): if cell.Offset(0, -13).value = "" then cell.offset(0,-13).value = cell.Value: Next`

Answer (score 1):

With @karma help, I was able to solve this problem!

```
Options Explicit
Sub UpdateReceivedInfo()

Dim wbInventory As Workbook
    Set wbInventory = Workbooks("IWI Inventory MASTER Report.xlsb")

    With wbInventory
        With wsPOTracker '<- worksheet codename
            
            Calculate '<-calculate all formulas
            
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData '<-checks if there is a filter, and clears the filter
                                
            'Filter Column "X" with no blanks
            .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=24, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
                
            'Set Range for Column("X") - [@[IWI RECEIVING QTY]]
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(24).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            'Loop through the visible rows in Table1 - Column "X", offset to Column "K", and paste the value.
            Dim cell As Range
            
            For Each cell In rng
                On Error Resume Next
                    cell.Offset(0, -13) = cell.Value2 '<- Offsets 13 columns, and returns the cell value
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next cell
    
            Calculate '<-refreshes the formulas
            .ShowAllData '<-clears the filter
            
        End With
        
        .Save 'saves the workbook
        
    End With
   
End Sub
```